# "git rm -r ." deleted my project

Tags: git

I had a project directory that wouldn't upload to git. I was trying to remove the origin to add a new origin. Somehow this command deleted all of my project files and I spent about 100 hours making. How can I get them back?

I also deleted the git repository after doing this lol

The page said `git rm` will not delete files from the local machine. What a lie!

Comment: Everything you committed should still be there. Do a `git checkout`.

Comment: Backups. Backups. Backups.

Comment: `git checkout ` returns a list of files but the folder the files were in are still empty

Comment: git hub is the backup. i have been commiting to local repository, but then just moved it to a new folder and tried to set up a remote. I should have copied it instead of done it on the original you're right.

Comment: just checkout the commit right before you deleted the files

Comment: or revert the commit deleting the files

Comment: Try `git reset HEAD`

Comment: I will not propose a solution but help you not worsen your problem. First, copy all the folder in another place before trying something. Second, are you sure you have ever committed these files? Can you tell us yes or no? If that's the case, don't stress, you will be able to restore them after some try. If you never committed them, git won't help you and they are definitely lost except if you try to restore them with an external tool (in this case, the backup copy made in the first time must be done to another drive!)

Comment: Calm down. Files you never committed in any git directory will be lost, but any file you ever committed can be recovered.

Comment: If git still lists the deleted files, it means you didn't delete the directory, but rather all files in the directory.

Comment: RIP app, it's gone along with the git repository. The page said git rm will not delete files from the local machine. What a lie!

Comment: When you've deleted the `.git` directory inside your project directory, then you've also deleted the local repository. But that wasn't done by `git rm -r .`. That's not git's fault.

Comment: `git rm` definitely removes files from the working directory. It's `git rm --cached` that removes from the index but not from the working directory. The manual says "git rm will not remove a file from just your working directory". Have you noticed the **just** part?

Oh, and "I also deleted the git repository after doing this lol". LOL, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have not committed:

```
git stash save
git stash drop
```

This is somewhat of a roundabout way fixing this, but requires less digging, and mostly foolproof. It'll be hard to screw it up.

Comment: Says `no local changes to save` and `no stash found`.

Comment: Then you must've committed, and this wasn't just a "git rm -r .". I would try "git reset --hard HEAD", next.

Comment: I also deleted the `.git` from inside of my IDE. I guess I learned what it was for. I was trying to clean up the `git` installation in order to start with a fresh `git init` since I was getting errors. Lol